# Best way to terminate a PowerShell function based on parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a few functions that get called either from Jenkins as part of a pipeline, they also get called from a pester test or lastly they can get called from the powershell console. The issue I have really stems from Jenkins not seeming to handle write-output in the way I think it should.

So what I am doing is creating a Boolean param that will allow my to choose if I terminate my function with a exit code or a return message. The exit code will be used by my pipeline logic and the return message for the rest ?

Is there a alternate approach I should be using this seems to be a bit of a hack.

```
function Get-ServerPowerState
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [string[]]$ilo_ip,
    [ValidateSet('ON', 'OFF')]
    [string]$Status,
    [boolean]$fail
)

BEGIN
{
    $here = Split-Path -Parent $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $Credentials = IMPORT-CLIXML "$($here)\Lib\iLOCred.xml"

}
PROCESS
{
    foreach ($ip in $ilo_ip)
    {
        New-LogEntry -Message ("Getting current powerstate " + $ip)
        If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ip.ToString() -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
            $hostPower = Get-HPiLOhostpower -Server $ip -Credential 
            $Credentials -DisableCertificateAuthentication
        }
    }

}
END
{

    If($fail){
        New-LogEntry -Message "Script been set to fail with exit code" -Log Verbose
        New-LogEntry -Message "The host is powered -  $($HostPower.Host_Power)" -Log Verbose

        If($hostPower.HOST_POWER -match $Status)
        {
            Exit 0
        }
        else {

            Exit 1
        }
    }
    else {
        New-LogEntry -Message "Script been set to NOT fail with exit code" -Log Verbose
        New-LogEntry -Message "The host is powered -  $($HostPower.Host_Power)" -Log Verbose
        If($hostPower.HOST_POWER -match $Status)
        {
            return 0
        }
        else {

            return 1
        }

    }


}
}
```

Comment: There's usually no reason to use `Write-Output`.  Why are you using it?  Also, `boolean param` tells me you should use a `[switch]`.  As always, post code with your question that relates otherwise the community at large can't help you.

Comment: Code added, the reason I tried to use the write-output is here [link](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/). This approach does not seem to be working for me as I am unable to work with the jenkins results. So my posted script is my approach, but this seems messy. The only alternative I can think of is two scripts, but the would be duplication of effort. @TheIncorrigible

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
function Get-Output {
  param ([switch]$asint)

  if ($asint) {
    return 1
  }
  else {
    write-output 'one'
  }
}

Get-Output

Get-Output -asint
```

If you intend to use the output in the pipeline then use Write-Output.  If you intend to only send it to the host process then use Write-Host.  I typically use the return keyword if I want to assign a return value to a variable.

```
[int]$result = Get-Output -asint
```